# Быстрое копирование объекта без изменения переменной

Tags: javascript

Требуется скопировать все поля объекта `a` в объект `b`, при этом `b=const`.

Объект `b` изначально может уже иметь некоторые свойства, их не должно быть в результате.

Есть ли более быстрое решение, чем это?

```js
const a = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
const b = {e: 1, f: 2, g: 3}

for (const key in b)
  delete b[key]

Object.assign(b, a)
```

Comment: а чем скорость этого решения не устраивает? смысл вообще именовать константой?

Comment: В последующем значение `b` замыкается другой функцией, к коду которой я не имею доступа.
Мне требуется изменить значение `b` так, чтобы не пришлось пересоздавать функцию.
Использую в своей либе для реакта.

`Proxy` не вариант т.к. получается намного медленнее.
Хочу узнать можно ли быстрее (либа про оптимизацию)

Comment: @VerZsuT, как ты замерял скорость? Почему думаешь, что будет медленнее?

Comment: @Grundy я не особо разбираюсь в нормальных тестах. Решил сейчас проверить на duzun.me, там 100_000 итераций примера выполняется 35мс, а код ниже в ответе 10мс.